# GnosisSafeProxy contract security issue

Tags: gnosis-safe

Basically if i created a Safe account, does it means the creator (me) will be the GnosisSafeProxy smart contract owner? Or all the owners in Safe account will be owners of the smart contract too?

Also, can i do transactions in Remix using GnosisSafeProxy smart contract source code?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do transasctions in remix . But you need some technical knowledge in order to use `execTransaction`` which is used to access the safe functionalities.

No only you will be the owner of the GnosisSafeProxy because GnosisSafeProxyFactory clone everytime a user request a new safe.

Hope this helps